# Модуль ElementTree. Как корректно записать все в один XML-файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Вот у меня функция, которая пишет данные в файл:

```
def lets_add_account(Event):
    list1.insert(END, add_account_entry_name.get())

    root = xml.Element("zSender")
    appt = xml.Element("accounts")
    root.append(appt)

    name = xml.SubElement(appt, "name")
    name.text = add_account_entry_name.get()

    login = xml.SubElement(appt, "login")
    login.text = add_account_entry_login.get()

    password = xml.SubElement(appt, "password")
    password.text = add_account_entry_login.get()

    tree = xml.ElementTree(root)
#   if not(os.path.exists("accounts.xml")):
    tree.write(open("accounts.xml", 'a'), encoding='unicode')
```

Но на выходе я получаю что попало... Как корректно при нажатии кнопки добавлять все в XML-файл? Может быть, это из-за лишнего добавления корня в начале функции? Уже даже не знаю... :(

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть структуру XML файла.

Comment: Корневой элемент accounts, а в нем name, login, password.